# Altered priors for classification trees

Tags: classification, decision-trees, cost-function

I am using the rpart function (in the "rpart" package) in R to fit a cost-sensitive classification tree. I have read the corresponding vignette, which says that misclassication costs are incorporated via altered priors (section 3.2.2 on page 8). However, I am not sure that I understand exactly how these altered probabilities affect the splitting criteria/impurity index. Does anyone know?

Comment: I have removed my answer. That seems something very `rpart` specific, and I don't know how that implementation works.